# Timer starts multiple times

Tags: java, android

```
Timer mytimer = new Timer();    
int i = 0;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mytimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
                 {
                    @Override
                    public void run () {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                     i++;
                                }
                            });
                       }
                  },0,1000);
```

Here is my code, after I ran the app on background for few minutes and returned to the app. The app started another timer (sometimes it doesn't starts) and there were two timers running. Please tell me how do I prevent it.

Comment: I would advise to `cancel` timer when activity stopped (in `onStop()`) and `scheduleAtFixedRate` when activity resumed (in `onResume()`).

Comment: That would work but the app has to run on background.

Comment: To be sure that your timer task will not be terminated as you move your activity to background you should start it from `Service`, not from `Activity`.

Comment: It worked, thanks.